# Prevent .htaccess to process further rules if current rule is applicable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am applying .htaccess to application coded in CodeIgnier.
By default, in order to remove index.php from the url you need to place one rule in htaccess file which is as follows.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

What basically above rule means is that redirect all the requests to the domain to index.php file.

What i want is, i want to add some more rules like follows

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?user=kids /kids
```

I am not sure how to do that because .htaccess processes the first rule mentioned above and does not redirect the /index.php?user=kids to /kids

Only solution i can think of is that if there is some way to prevent .htaccess file to further process the rules if the current one matches.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3):

The [L] flag does exactly this. You could add

```
RewriteRule ^index.php\?user=kids$ /kids [R=301,L]
```

and it would work.